# MVC Routing issue when changing place holder from {controller} to {controller1}

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have changed the default routing to

```
routes.MapRoute("Default",
               "{controller1}/{action1}",
               new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"}
               )
```

if i use url as "/MvcDemo/"(Here MVC demo is my project)
I start getting Http 403.14 error

if i use "/MvcDemo/home/index" it works fine 
and another url "/MvcDemo/player/details" is also mapping to the defaults
even though such controller with the action method exists

Can any one help me how controller1/action1 may have caused this issue

Comment: 403 is forbidden... this could be caused due to permissions on your folder, but ALSO by duplicated names on your resources. E.g. You have a folder with the same Action Name and the IIS tries to dispatch the resource, instead of the routed request.

Comment: Try to add `action1 = UrlParameter.Optional` to the defaults object, as well as `controller1`. Also your route will always map to the default `Index(string controller1, string action1)` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third parameter there is for default values. You've changed the placeholder names, but you haven't changed the default value names. So, essentially there's no default `controller1` or `action1` value to fill in the route with if it's missing, which is why the `/MvcDemo/` route fails.

Comment: But when i type /MvcDemo/home/index it maps to Home Controller and Index method why that so and even /MvcDemo/player/details maps to default values of Home and Index even though i have PlayerController class with details index method why that is so.

Comment: thanks for your reply could u explain me why above behaviour is there

Comment: Because in both of those cases you are *passing* the values for `controller1` and `action1`, it's only when you don't pass a value, that it falls back to the defaults, which in this case, don't exist.